# Handling multiple selections result in "Value Relation Widget" in QGIS

Tags: qgis, array, widget, relation

Using the "Allow multiple selections" in the "Value Relation Widget" results in `{value1,value2,...}`. But arrays in QGIS are written like `['value1','value2',...]`.

How do I handle the multiple selection results? For example, if I would get the first entry in my list. With usual arrays, I would use this syntax: `array_get('array',0)`.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This may help:

```
array_get( string_to_array( substr( "array", 2, -1 ) ), 0)
```

Or

```
with_variable(
    'arr',
    string_to_array( substr("array", 2, -1)),
    array_get( @arr, 0)
)
```

Answer (score 9):

This is a map with only keys. You can get them using `map_akeys('yourmap')` which will turn it into an array of all keys.

So your syntax could be  `map_akeys('yourmap')[0]` or `array_get(map_akeys('yourmap'),0)`

Similary you could use `map_avals('yourmap')` to get all values or `map_get('yourmap','key')` to get a specific value.

Comment: By using: 'array_get(map_akeys("lage_weg"),0)' I got that: 'Eval Error: Cannot convert '{259}' to map' - 259 is one of the keys

Comment: Just rolled back my edit because it is not a set either due to missing quotations. Its just a badly formatted string :D Sorry, dont have a solution at the moment. Maybe just try the solution Kadir Şahbaz provided.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wanting a readable list as output I found cleaning out the unwanted characters easiest.

```
replace("Your_attribute",array('{','}','"'),'' )
```