# Translating array into list or map and back in QGIS

Tags: qgis, expression, list, array, qgis-widget

Arrays in QGIS look like:

```
[ 'WID00037-LDB', 'WID00027-LDB', 'WID00026-LDB' ]
```

This kind of List or Map generated by QGIS Value-Relation Widget look like this:

```
{ "WID00037-LDB", "WID00027-LDB", "WID00026-LDB" }
```

(This seems to be a List with key but without values. Or it is just something else?)

How do I turn this kind of List/Map into a array and vice versa? I prefer QGIS expression for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays are just list of values whereas maps are `key:value` pairs. So there is missing some information how you want to deal with the `key` part of the map. Conceptually, you can't simply convert arrays to maps and vice versa without adding information (when creating a map) or loosing information (the key) when creating an array.

Based on this, I doubt you really have a map and not rather a string containing curly brackets `{}`. In any case, these cases have to be treated separately.

### String

If the part containing curly brackets `{}` is a string, you have to remove the curly brackets (e.g. using `regexp_replace()`) and than convert the string to an array with `string_to_array()`:

```
string_to_array( 
    regexp_replace( 
        '{ "WID00037-LDB", "WID00027-LDB", "WID00026-LDB" }',
        ('{|}'),
        ''
    )
)
```

### Map

To generate a map, you can use the funtion [`from_json()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#from-json). It expects a string as argument with this syntax ([see help](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#from-json)):

```
from_json('{"qgis":"rocks"}') → { 'qgis': 'rocks' }
```

So you have to format your array as string first and respect this syntax. Than you can convert this string to a map. The expression looks like this:

```
from_json( 
    '{'  || array_to_string (
        array_foreach (
            array ('WID00037-LDB', 'WID00027-LDB', 'WID00026-LDB'),
            '"' || @element || '":'  || '"'  || @element  ||  '"'
        )
    )  || '}'
)
```

The result of this expression:

Input array: `[ 'A', 'B', 'C' ]`

Output map: `{ 'A': 'A', 'B': 'B', 'C': 'C' }`

Comment: yes, maps usually are key:value - but not if it's created with the QGIS Value-Relation Widget: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/395598/how-to-handle-the-allow-multiple-selections-in-value-relation-widget-results

Comment: Can you share a (dummy) project that illustrates the use case? I suspect the output is not a map, but a string with curly brackets: `{}`? A map without keys is not valid, at least Im not able to reproduce a case with a valid map without keys and values.

Comment: I can't rely create a dummy to illustrate this case, it's complicated: I have to fill a field by expression (with all features in the near using `overlay_nearest`). The result is a nice array, but the field I've to fill uses the Value-Relation Widget. This Widget (I don't like it but need it) creates this kind `{"..."}`-list from the user selection and can't understand the list from the expression.

Comment: So cant you create a string by concatenating the curly brackets with the values and insert this to the widget?

Comment: Yes, that's the way I will go! Thanks!